# Распознать цифры и "+-" на картинке

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети

Вот примеры картинок, где нужно извлечь символы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал сделать с помощью pytesseract, но ничего не выходит.
Вместо цифр выводит либо буквы либо вообще не может распознать.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

image_path = '/root/Downloads/captcha/captcha.png'

im = Image.open(image_path)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config='-c 
tessedit_char_whitelist=+-0123456789')
print(text)
```

Comment: А вы пробовали использовать не свою конфигурацию, а встроенные Файлы для математических символов?

Comment: обесцветь и инвертируй картинку прежде чем tesseract'у на распознание отдавать...